# AngularJS: $setPristine() doesn't clear input types of 'URL'

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have just found and started using the $setPistine() function to actually clear a form and empty all fields.

I have been having a few issues, it seems to work with standard

```
   input type='text'
```

but input types of 'url' it doesn't clear.

I have a jsfiddle here

```
      http://jsfiddle.net/martinlondon/Urt5K/2/
```

Actually I have been having a similar issue with a standard text input type but with a a cusotm validation directive attached, this doesn't concern me that much as i have access to the validation code.

But the input type ='url' should work.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

**EDIT**

Updated fiddler is it was incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setPristine()` is not supposed to clear the input, only mark that the user hasn't changed its value (see [docs](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController), search for "$pristine").

E.g. you load a form and the "Price:" field says "100 €". At this time `pristine=true`. You change it to "200 €": `pristine=false`. You somehow reset the form, the value returns to "100 €" and `pristine` to `true`. If you clear this field, it has changed, thus `pristine=false`.

Comment: Thanks, yes that is true but along with clearing the model ?? i.e.       $scope.myform = {};
        $scope.formName.$setPristine();

Comment: Nikos, i am going to mark this question as answered, as you pointed out setPristine is working as expected. I have another issue with model updating on type='url', i will open up another question.

Comment: But yes, in order to clear the form and mark it pristine you do something along the lines of `$scope.myform = {}; $scope.formName.$setPristine();`. Actually if you are using the `$pristine` infrastructure, you should probably `$setPristine()` each time you set a value to the form.